# Force positive weight keras

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, keras

I don't find the way to force the weight of my layer to be positive ( on Keras 1.2.2)

Do you know a way to force positive weight ?

Thx,

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the constraint function here: https://keras.io/constraints/

If you want non negative output you can use 'relu' activation function on your output layer.

Answer (score 9):

I find the answer !!

In Keras 1.2.2 :

```
 from keras.constraints import maxnorm, nonneg

 x = Dense(1, bias=0, W_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01),W_constraint=nonneg())(input_sequences)
```

Comment: It's `kernel_constraint=` now instead of `W_constraint=`. Thanks for directly answering the question.

Comment: It's also `non_neg` now